# JNDI for Oracle 11 doesn't work in TC Server

Tags: oracle, spring

I'm trying for a few days configure a JNDI for Oracle 11 in TC Server, but no success. The intresting thing is when I do exactly the same thing for the Oracle 9, it works fine. My first though was the oracle jar file, but I'm using the newst one. So here my configurations and the error. If someone can give me a hint I will appreciate vey much.

In my application I have:
applicationContext.xml (I use Spring 3, Hiberante and JPA for access the DB) here is only the JNDI, if someone needs more info here please let me know.

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="oracle11DataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/oracle11DataSource"`/>
```

web.xml

```
   <resource-ref>
     <res-ref-name>jdbc/oracle11DataSource</res-ref-name>
     <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
     <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
 </resource-ref>
```

Server.xml:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>

    <Resource 
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" 
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory" 
        maxActive="2" 
        maxIdle="1" 
        maxWait="5000" 
        name="jdbc/oracle11DataSource" 
        password="pwd" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostName:1521:SID" 
        username="username" 
        validationQuery="select 1"/> 

  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

I added the ojdbc6.jar in the lib folder of the server. When I start The TC Server here the Stack trace:

```
7/01/2011 8:39:28 AM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.sql.SQLException
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:208)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:157)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:617)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:561)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:427)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:132)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:94)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:477)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:216)
 at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:140)
 at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:304)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:793)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:781)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1020)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:629)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:237)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4540)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:807)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:202)
 ... 32 more
7/01/2011 8:39:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException
7/01/2011 8:39:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
7/01/2011 8:39:29 AM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool init
WARNING: maxIdle is larger than maxActive, setting maxIdle to: 100
7/01/2011 8:39:29 AM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.sql.SQLException
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:208)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:157)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:617)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:561)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:427)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:132)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:94)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:477)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:216)
 at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:140)
 at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:304)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:793)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:781)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:781)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:781)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
 at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:152)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:807)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:202)
 ... 57 more
2011-01-07 08:39:29,062 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oracle11DataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:807)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:805)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:781)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:781)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:781)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
 at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:152)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
 ... 27 more
```

I agree. I'm also used to put the tag in the context.xml. I put into server.xml because in the TC Server documentation the example say to put in the server.xml: http://static.springsource.com/projects/tc-server/6.0/admin/cadmresourcelink.html

If I put the resouce in the context.xml here the error:

```
2011-01-07 13:24:20,234 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Listener refused the connection with the following error:
    ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
     )
    2011-01-07 13:24:20,234 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lastUpdatedController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.controller.configuration.ApplicationData com.controller.component.LastUpdatedController.applicationData; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.controller.configuration.ApplicationData#0' defined in URL [file:/C:/tools/springsource-2.5-ga/tc-server-developer-2.0.4.RELEASE/tomcat-6.0.29.A.RELEASE/wtpwebapps/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/user.interface.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:807)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.controller.configuration.ApplicationData com.controller.component.LastUpdatedController.applicationData; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.controller.configuration.ApplicationData#0' defined in URL [file:/C:/tools/springsource-2.5-ga/tc-server-developer-2.0.4.RELEASE/tomcat-6.0.29.A.RELEASE/wtpwebapps/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/user.interface.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
        ... 28 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.controller.configuration.ApplicationData#0' defined in URL [file:/C:/tools/springsource-2.5-ga/tc-server-developer-2.0.4.RELEASE/tomcat-6.0.29.A.RELEASE/wtpwebapps/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/user.interface.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:844)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
        ... 30 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:311)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.ajc$afterThrowing$org_springframework_orm_jpa_aspectj_JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect$1$18a1ac9(JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.aj:15)
        at com..domain.configuration.PropertyGroup_Roo_Entity.findAllPropertyGroups_aroundBody4(PropertyGroup_Roo_Entity.aj:91)
        at com..domain.configuration.PropertyGroup_Roo_Entity.ajc$interMethod$com._configuration_PropertyGroup_Roo_Entity$com_domain_configuration_PropertyGroup$findAllPropertyGroups(PropertyGroup_Roo_Entity.aj:1)
        at com..domain.configuration.PropertyGroup.findAllPropertyGroups(PropertyGroup.java:1)
        at com..controller.configuration.ApplicationData.load(ApplicationData.java:18)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1544)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        ... 40 more
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1235)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1168)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:250)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:310)
        at $Proxy45.getResultList(Unknown Source)
        ... 51 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1616)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:717)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2192)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2187)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:452)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1258)
        at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:241)
        ... 57 more
    Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Listener refused the connection with the following error:
    ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
     )
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
        ... 71 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the pool will run the validation query during initialization.

But if that happens then your validation query might be the problem because `select 1` is not a valid Oracle statement. You need to use `select 1 from dual`

But then I would expect to see a different error message.

**Edit**
Another thing:

Are you sure your <GlobalNamingResource> tag is correct?

All JNDI DataSources that I have used so far where put into the web application's context.xml into a `<Resource>` tag.

```
<Context>
  <Resource name="jdbc/oracle11DataSource" 
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            ..../>
</Context>
```

Basically the way it is described in the Tomcat manual:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources

**Edit 2**
The error message *TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor* clearly shows that the value for `SID` in the JDBC URL is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, I didn't really expect the wrong validation query to throw such an error (but it would have caused a problem anyway)

Comment: I update the issue with the "new" error after put the resource tag in the context.xm instead server.xml

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in one of my projects for the error message "TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor "c
i could connect through sql developer with the sid but not through the webserver and fixed the problem by changing

url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521:sid"

to

url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521/sid"